# Creating PDF map with legend using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

Once I've mapped all the points, how do I create a legend and a title for the map?

Comment: That's a very broad question.. a broad answer is to use the composer. http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/making_a_map.html

Comment: I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Answer (score 2):

Read the manual.

In particular:

- [Creating a Basic Map](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/training_manual/basic_map/index.html)
- [Creating Maps](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/training_manual/map_composer/index.html)
- [Adding a Title](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/training_manual/map_composer/map_composer.html#basic-fa-adding-a-title)
- [Adding a Legend](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/training_manual/map_composer/map_composer.html#basic-fa-adding-a-legend)
- [Exporting Your Map](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/training_manual/map_composer/map_composer.html#basic-fa-exporting-your-map) (explicitly documents exporting to PDF in the example)

If you still have trouble after reading all of these, then you will need to post a more specific question.